# In Crystal reports can I supress the time from a datetime column in Totext

Tags: crystal-reports

In a formula we want to handle nulls but we are getting the time, is there a way to only show the date here not the date and time?

```
IF YEAR({CYCLECOUNT_BY_BIN.LASTCOUNT})<2000 THEN '' ELSE 
TOTEXT({CYCLECOUNT_BY_BIN.LASTCOUNT},)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all that is needed:
ToText({Date field}, 'MM/dd/yyyy')